# Android device is not supported for my application - why?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

This is a list of permissions from my app's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="768"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="false"/>
```

Why does Galaxy Tab 3 8.0 not support it? (I tried to remove HARDWARE_TEST and VIBRATE and did not make any difference)

Comment: possibly the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` permission since it does not have a phone? or the `requiresSmalletWidthDp` value? I dont know what the galaxy tab 3 width dp is

Comment: @tyczj it perfectly runs on other tablets which do not have "phone" functionality either

Comment: what about the smallestWidthDP? is that bigger than what the galaxy tab 3 is?

Comment: the screen is "800 x 1280 pixels, 8.0 inches (~189 ppi pixel density)" [http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_3_8_0-5456.php]

Comment: Just try without the phone permission, and then without the smallestWidthDP setting, and see if anything is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the foll into the manifest did the trick:

```
 <supports-screens
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="768"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
 />
```